# Returning a list back to the function

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This is my code. Im using the function to retrieve the list but its not sending it.

```
public List<string> country_set()   
{
    mCountryUrl = new Uri ("http://xxxxxxx.wwww/restservice/country");
    mList = new List<string> ();
    mCountry = new List<Country> ();
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    client.DownloadDataAsync (mCountryUrl);
    client.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender, e) => {
        RunOnUiThread (() => {
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (e.Result);
            mCountry = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>> (json);
            Console.WriteLine (mCountry.Count.ToString());
            int x = mCountry.Count;
            for(int i=0; i< x ; i++)
            {
                mList.Add(mCountry[i].name);
            }
        });
    };
    return mList;
}
```

It throws an exception . 
Kindly help me out

Comment: Which exception do you get ?

Comment: And what line throws that exception?

Comment: Unless it's a design pattern of android, it seems suspect that you're returning a list with 0 elements, and dispatch a thread to add items to that list (which is also not threadsafe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you return the mList immediately after your method completes which is before the call to the web server completes. Now after your calling code inspects the list to find it empty, eventually the call to the server will complete and your list will be filled which is too late!

This will fix the problem:

```
        var mCountryUrl = new Uri("http://xxxxxxx.wwww/restservice/country");
        var mList = new List<string>();
        var mCountry = new List<Country>();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        var data = client.DownloadData(mCountryUrl);

        string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        mCountry = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(mCountry.Count.ToString());
        int x = mCountry.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            mList.Add(mCountry[i].name);

        }

        return mList;
```

Comment: This is NOT asynchronous as the poster's version was (trying to be).

Comment: I just wanted to show them how to correct their code, to return data. In your answer you've correctly implemented it in an async manner.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
public async Task<List<string>> country_set() 
{ 
    mCountryUrl = new Uri ("http://xxxxxxx.wwww/restservice/country");
    mList = new List<string>(); 
    mCountry = new List<Country>();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] data = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(mCountryUrl); 
    string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); 
    mCountry = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>> (json);
    Console.WriteLine (mCountry.Count.ToString()); 
    int x = mCountry.Count; 
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)        
        mList.Add(mCountry[i].name);         

    return mList; 
}
```

It uses the new async model from .Net.

EDIT: Code is typed from the Android app. Anyone who spots syntax mistakes (or any other kind), please signal them in a comment.